# What does “Wireless-men” mean?

Tags: meaning

In All Quiet on the Western Front, the narrator says,

> In the meantime we receive visitors, a couple of wireless-men, who are generously invited to the feed. They sit in the living-room where there is a piano.

Could someone please explain to me what "Wireless-men" means? I've looked on google, and I can't find anything remotely useful. It might just be because I'm bad at using it though :P.

I'd greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: I would assume the same as "radio operators".

Comment: Please pick one site to post [your question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/5534) on. Cross posting [is not OK](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/323179).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*All Quiet on the Western Front* was published in November 1928 in Germany.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_Quiet_on_the_Western_Front)

'Wireless Telegraphy', which is the transmission of signals (not the sound of a voice), was still only in the hands of Governments, not the general public or commercial companies.

> The transmission of sound (radiotelephony) began to displace wireless telegraphy by the **1920s** for many applications, making possible radio broadcasting. **Wireless telegraphy** continued to be used for private person-to-person business, governmental, and military communication, such as telegrams and diplomatic communications, and evolved into radioteletype networks.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_telegraphy)

**'Wireless-men'** would have referred to Government employees engaged in Signals Intelligence. (Our equivalent would be GCHQ in the UK or the NSA in the USA.)

> From the mid-twenties, **German Military Intelligence Abwehr** began intercepting and cryptanalyzing diplomatic traffic. Under Hermann Göring, the Nazi Research Bureau (Forschungsamt or “FA”) had units for intercepting domestic and international communications.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signals_intelligence_in_modern_history)